# How to properly implement boolean logic

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch for logging within an application. I need to write a log viewer that filters on all the fields of my document.

My documents look like this:

```
    "_source": {
       "timestamp": 1373502012000,
       "userId": 6,
       "paId": 56331,
       "lId": 6,
       "prId": 2,
       "vId": 6336,
       "actionType": "LOAD_DATA"
    }
```

`actionType` is an enum (Java).

I need to write a ElasticSearch equivalent to the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM snapshot.action_log_item 

WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1372718783286 AND 1372718783286

AND userId=6 
AND paId=56331 
AND lId=6 
AND prId=2 
AND vId=6336
AND (
    actionType='LOAD_DATA' OR 
    actionType='SAVE_DATA' OR 
    actionType='LOG_IN'
);
```

Please help me write a properly nested query and/or filter to get a result equivalent to my SQL statement.

**EDIT** Here's my current code (that works without the `{ "or"...` portion).

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [ {
        "term" : {
          "userId" : 6
        }
      }, {
        "term" : {
          "lId" : 6
        }
      }, {
        "term" : {
          "vId" : 6336
        }
      } ]
    }
  },
  "filter" : {
    "and" : {
      "filters" : [ {
        "term" : {
          "paId" : 56331
        }
      }, {
        "range" : {
          "timestamp" : {
            "from" : 1372718783286,
            "to" : 1377643583286,
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true
          }
        }
      }, {
        "or" : {
          "filters" : [ {
            "term" : {
              "actionType" : "LOAD_DATA"
            }
          }, {
            "term" : {
              "actionType" : "SAVE_DATA"
            }
          }, {
            "term" : {
              "actionType" : "LOG_IN"
            }
          } ]
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: The following query works. It's not the same query as above, but it returns the expected result. It seems that these filters/queries don't work on the `actionType` field.

```
{
  "size": 30, 
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "uId": 6
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "loId": 6
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "prId": 2
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "paId": [
                  56331,
                  56298
                ],
                "minimum_should_match": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "from": 1372718783286,
            "to": 1377643583286,
            "include_lower": true,
            "include_upper": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{or...` portion should like this:

```
{
  "or": [
    {
      "term": {
        "actionType": "LOAD_DATA"
      }
    },
    {
      "term": {
        "actionType": "SAVE_DATA"
      }
    },
    {
      "term": {
        "actionType": "LOG_IN"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can check the doc for that filter [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/or-filter/)

**Edit**

As I see you are having problems I rewrote your query. I hope it helps

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "userId": 6
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "paId": 56331
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "lId": 6
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "prId": 2
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "vId": 6336
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "actionType": [
                  "LOAD_DATA",
                  "SAVE_DATA",
                  "LOG_IN"
                ],
                "minimum_should_match": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "from": 1372718783286,
            "to": 1377643583286,
            "include_lower": true,
            "include_upper": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically I put the date range as filter and the other conditions are `term` queries inside the `must` clause of the boolean query. You can see that the `or` part is now inside the `must` clause as a `terms` query that act as `or` between those 3 values.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. That didn't work for me, but I think I got it working just now by using a different query. I'll post what I did once I confirm it works for other cases.

Comment: Ok well I thought my solution worked, but it didn't. Your solution returned 0 results. I tried the exact syntax of the documentation page too. Any other ideas?

Comment: I edited the post and rewrite the query. I can't test it but it should work.

Comment: That didn't work either. It returned 0 hits. Your query works as expected without the "terms" portion. After an entire day of slaving over this, I no longer think it is a syntax issue. I tried using a "terms" query, an "or" filter, and some other methods, but none worked for the `actionType` field. However, all those tests worked on all the `Id` fields (integers). Is there any reason it wouldn't work on Strings?

Comment: I added a second Edit to my original question to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: Check your mapping a see if the field actionType is being analyzed. If not you should change that for not analyzing it (or you can use a query string instead of term query). The other fields are not affected because they are int

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue. The field was being analyzed. But due to a new design decision, that field is going to change into an integer, so I'll use the terms filter.